# How can I make Silverlight controls invisible to mouse actions?

Tags: wpf, uielement, silverlight-2-rc0

How can I get a `UIElement` to ignore mouse clicks on it and pass it through to the control behind it?

I have a 50% transparent `UIElement` which covers another element. When I attempt to click on the background element, the mouse click is captured by the foreground semi-transparent `UIElement`.

Comment: Like is required to implement the new "clickjacking" exploit, you mean?

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of "clickjacking", but I was more thinking of a selection rectangle. I.e. click on an item to select it, click again to unselect - except when I click the second time, the selection rect swallows the event.

Comment: Sorry Mark, it's a brand new exploit and it was far too specific a question to let slip by without flagging up the potential security risks of such an implementation.  http://www.theregister.co.uk/2008/10/07/clickjacking_surveillance_zombie/

Comment: Hmm... That is nasty. I think I was change the selection rectangle to just be a selection border. At least then the click will go through to my object without being swallowed.
Thanks for the link, the video was very interesting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set `IsHitTestVisible=false`